# On touched area Zoom/scale imageview

Tags: android, image, bitmap, zooming, scale

I have implemented on-touch zoom method for zoom image and it's work perfect but i want to scale that part of touched area of image will be scale And that touched area only need to change the position or scaled

for e.g : i have one Transparent image of two ball if i will touch on one ball and drag it to nearest to another then only that ball will be scaled.

```
private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
        "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int action = event.getAction();
int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
        || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) 
 {
    sb.append("(pid ").append(
            action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
    sb.append(")");
}
sb.append("[");
for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) 
{
    sb.append("#").append(i);
    sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
    sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
    sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
    if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
        sb.append(";");
}
sb.append("]");
Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
}

  @Override   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)    {  
ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
dumpEvent(event);

// Handle touch events here...
switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
    start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
    Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
    mode = DRAG;
    break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
    oldDist = spacing(event);
    Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
    if (oldDist > 10f) {
        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        midPoint(mid, event);
        mode = ZOOM;
        Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
    }
    break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
    mode = NONE;
    Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
    break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    if (mode == DRAG) {
        // ...
        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()
                - start.y);
    } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
        float newDist = spacing(event);
        Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
        if (newDist > 10f) {
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            float scale = newDist / oldDist;
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
        }
    }
    break;
}
view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
return true;
}

/** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}
```

Is there any possibility to get that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think from your query you want to implement drag image after zoom it(double click ) ,may be your zoom is working perfectly but you want add some lazy draging animation after zoom it so i give you Full tested Zoom in/out /drage imageview class just replaced it with your oldone
i hop it worked for you
sorry i have try many times but duue to charector limit can't past code hear so i am giving you url please go and find class
thanks
[TOuchview class link click on it](http://bitxpert.in/jayman/TouchImageView.java)

Comment: i think from your query you want to implement drag image after zoom it(double click )  ------ But if i am going to drag it then it would be drag both ball i just want only one object to be dragged.

Comment: Dear wayne its look like you want to play with area of image like dreamland If i am not wrong then you have image of two ball in single image now after zoom you want move only one ball not other in single image ..so i think it not possible with image view  However you after calculating view area you can draw it and drop it I mens you can play batter in CANVAS just search it and if you found solution then please let me know thanks

Comment: yes exactly now you are getting my point.. @jayman and i have less knowledge of canvas so if you have any link related to that then it will be help full for me...